# Facebook page URL blocked by facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm getting this error message when i try to share my page in a post or in a comment:

> the content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to find out what's on your page is detected as unsafe. Usually, you can find some helpful warnings there. If there is nothing suspicious - you've probably caught false positive and you have two options:

1. Report a bug to facebook team
2. Use dynamic urls that are unique for each post

This may also happen when this urls has received too many users claims (this may be seen in dashboard) - in this case you should use dynamic urls only.

And, of course, be good ;) Do not spam users. Throttle automatic posts if any. Make sure your page content is appropriate for most of age groups.

Comment: My clients' url got blocked for sharing on Facebook and when I use the sharing debugger I got only this message:"We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know."
How can I know what is the problem? I'm struggling with this issue for few hours now and find nothing useful on the web or on Facebook developers. The website has nothing "abusive or malicious", it's just a simple jewelry website.

Comment: You've probably shared this url too frequently. Contact Facebook support or, as I mentioned above, use dynamic url